# How to tell "that I am not against/countering your opinion" politely?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrases, conversation

The one situation that happens most of the time, when I converse with my Boss was that When he misunderstands some point and talks from that view and if I want to correct him, He mistakes me that I am confronting, countering or against his opinion. But actually not. In that situation, what is the right sentence that I could use to politely address the issue and stress the importance of my point.

Currently, I am using "I am not against your point or countering your idea" sort of, but with that I could not make him listen to me. instead, makes the situation worsen. is there any other sentence that I could use, which would be polite and at the same time effective to make him listen as well.

Comment: Honestly this has little to do with English and more to do with your boss' personality.  If you need an apology of any kind then you've already crossed some kind of line to make him upset.  If you really want to work for someone you can't confront, then you need to modify your "countering" argument to be less *confrontational*.   Saying, "I'm sorry, I didn't meant to sound like I was against you," is not really helping the situation.  Which is to say, if you have a boss who doesn't appreciate your opinion, perhaps it's better not to offer it in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest the phrase

> I am not trying to be critical.

Here is a typical sentence that uses it.

> I'm not trying to be critical here, because I do believe there is validity to Elliot's work, but I personally have had trouble using it. - [Trading Commodities and Financial Futures](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=T8Z_S0lcJb0C&pg=PT229&dq=%22not%20trying%20to%20be%20critical%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjc-OvQvvXYAhWDabwKHYs2CngQ6AEIPjAE#v=onepage&q=%22not%20trying%20to%20be%20critical%22&f=false)

ELL can only answer questions concerning the English language. You might get a wider range of suggestions for dealing with the problems with your boss on [Workplace stack exchange](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you. While conversing, will "I am not trying to be critical." be natural to use? thanks for suggesting workplace stack exchange. Could you comment on my current way of doing it " I am not countering"  and "I am not against you" sentences?

Comment: Your suggestions are grammatically correct, but a positive wording might be more effective. If you can honestly say "I agree with you about...", that would be much more effective than saying "I am not against you".

Answer (score 0):

This is really not a question about English. The situation described is that you believe or perhaps know that your boss is wrong about something: he "misunderstands." When you counter your boss's words, however politely, you **are** disagreeing, and your boss will know that.

Sadly, some bosses do not tolerate disagreement gracefully (or at all). Many bosses dislike **public** disagreement. A few bosses welcome disagreement except in dire emergencies or after a final decision has been made. How best to contradict a superior depends on circumstances: a boss's personality, an imminent threat to life or property, a meeting to start planning, a public or private interaction, and, very importantly, whether the item to be contradicted is a one of fact or of opinion. A single verbal formula will come nowhere close to covering all the factual and social contingencies. How to respond during a crisis and how to participate in a brainstorming meeting should differ.

Here is one approach that is often but not invariably useful. Suggest somehow that he may not yet be aware of a relevant fact. Between "did I forget to tell you about X" and "did you forget about X," the first sounds like an effort to be helpful whereas the second sounds like a criticism. When something is not a matter of fact but rather of opinion, another approach is to start with something like "may I offer a suggestion": that recognizes your boss's authority rather than challenging it.

Comment: Thank you. that's a lot of information. I am reading it again and again. so I do not miss any.